# ViewFlipper in Fragment (TabHost) child not shown until touch on it

Tags: java, android

I have a Tab (suing Fragments) and the Tab content is actually a View Flipper.

The first page of the Flipper shows list of images. When I click to some of the items I go to Flipper's page 2. Which will show the image in Full Screen. When I click Back it goes to the List View (with all images). Everything works as expected until I put in and out animations to the ViewFlipper. After I set in Animation to be some Translate animation, I see nothing, until I touch the screen. When I touch the screen I see the image, and if not, I see empty tab content.

I am using ViewFlipper and Fragments from the support package.

Is this some sort of expected behavior or an issue?

**ADDED ANIMATIONS**

left_to_right_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="-220%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

left_to_right_out.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="220%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

right_to_left_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="220%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

right_to_left_out.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-220%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

And then I use them like this:

When I want to show the second child of the view flipper:

```
mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.left_to_right_in));
mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.left_to_right_out));
mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

When I want to go back to the first child:

```
mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.right_to_left_in));
mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.right_to_left_out));
mViewFlipper.showNext();
```

Comment: Those animations could be the reason for that behavior. Can you add them to the question?

Comment: added them in the question. thanks.

Comment: Is this the only animation you used? The `ViewFlipper` has a `in` and an `out` animation.

Comment: no I have used 4 animations, but most of them differ in the fromXDelta/toXDelta parameter. Actually all of them differ in that param.

Comment: Well those parameters are quite important. Can you please add all the animations mentioning how you use them in/out?

Comment: Ok I added the whole logic of defining the animations and using them with my View Flipper :)

Comment: The animations look fine, also I don't see why you would not see the first page of the `ViewFlipper` after adding them. As a small test can you simply use only one of the sets of animations for both cases and see if the behavior persists?

Comment: I have used these animations hundreds of times and they work fine, only peculiar scenario is as described in the first question (which was obvious from the start without all the 'post this', 'post that' chit-chat. Thanks for the effort anyway :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem.I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: nope, something fixed the issue but not sure what :( sorry

Comment: Anyone knows how to solve this issue? I could really use your help.